# Am I supposed to create a new socket connection for each packet?

Tags: sockets, tcp

Examples for TCP/IP always seem show the socket being closed and the application terminated at the end.

Am I supposed to create a socket and then close it after each new packet? Or do I leave the connection open and only close the socket when the client is exited?

Comment: The examples are correct.

Comment: Leave it open, of course.